# payment refund visa uk

Tags: visas, uk

I made the registration from Brazil.
I did the procedure for the visa but then I had to cancel, I did not go to take my biometric data, I did not receive any mail from the home office. When I cancel I just received an email saying that I must wait until the decision is made. And a month later I still do not receive the refund.

Did someone go through something similar and how did I come to solve it?

Comment: Have you contacted the visa processing centre?

Comment: STILL DO NOT CONTACT ME, CANCELING THE ORDER AND REQUESTING THE REIMBURSEMENT WAS ENOUGH